# What is the correct regular expression for finding specific pattern in these lines?

Tags: java, regex, string

So I have one large file that contains a bunch of weather data. I have to allocate each line from the large file into its corresponding state file. So there will be a total of 50 new state files with their own data.

The large file contains ~1 million lines of records like this:

```
COOP:166657,'NEW IBERIA AIRPORT ACADIANA REGIONAL LA US',200001,177,553
```

Although the name of the station can vary and have different number of words.

This is the regular expression I am using:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".* ([A-Z][A-Z]) US.*"); 
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
```

When I run my program there are still instances of lines in which the pattern could not be found.

This is my program:

```
package climate;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * This program will read in a large file containing many stations and states,
 * and output in order the stations to their corresponding state file.
 * 
 * Note: This take a long time depending on processor. It also appends data to
 * the files so you must remove all the state files in the current directory
 * before running for accuracy.
 * 
 * @author Marcus
 *
 */

public class ClimateCleanStates {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out
                .println("Note: This program can take a long time depending on processor.");
        System.out
                .println("It is also not necessary to run as state files are in this directory.");
        System.out
                .println("But if you would like to see how it works, you may continue.");
        System.out.println("Please remove state files before running.");
        System.out.println("\nIs the States directory empty?");
        String answer = in.nextLine();

        if (answer.equals("N")) {
            System.exit(0);
            in.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Would you like to run the program?");
        String answer2 = in.nextLine();
        if (answer2.equals("N")) {
            System.exit(0);
            in.close();
        }

        String[] statesSpaced = new String[51];

        File statefile, dir, infile;

        // Create files for each states
        dir = new File("States");
        dir.mkdir();


        infile = new File("climatedata.csv");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(infile);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String line;
        System.out.println();

        // Read in climatedata.csv
        // Probably need to implement ClimateRecord class
        final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // Remove instances of -9999

            if (!line.contains("-9999")) {



                        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.* ([A-Z][A-Z]) US.*$"); 
                        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
                        String stateFileName = null;

                        if(m.find()){
                            //System.out.println(m.group(1));
                            stateFileName = m.group(1);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Could not find abbreviation");
                        }

                        /*
                        stateFileName = "States/" + stateFileName + ".csv";
                        statefile = new File(stateFileName);

                        FileWriter stateWriter = new FileWriter(statefile, true);
                        stateWriter.write(line + "\n");
                        // Progress reporting
                        System.out.printf("Writing [%s] to file [%s]\n", line,
                                statefile);
                        stateWriter.flush();
                        stateWriter.close();
                        */





            }
        }
        System.out.println("Elapsed " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
        br.close();
        fr.close();
        in.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: As i can see, name of station is surrounded by single quotes, why you don't just search for pairs of them?

Comment: As it turns out, some of the line do not contain state abbreviations

Comment: I would output files based off of station but it has to grouped by state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need look around functions, they assert that something should precede or follow the expression you're matching but not be included in the result.

```
(?<= )[A-Z][A-Z](?= US)
```

`(?<= )` must be a space before

`[A-Z][A-Z]` exactly two capital letters

`(?= US)` must be a space and the letters US after

It might pay to be more robust with the look around: (?= US) could be (?= US',) for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want to extract exaclty, but if you use a pattern of type

```
Pattern.compile("(.*):(.*),'(.*)',(.*),(.*),(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
if(m.find()) {
  // here you can use with i from 1 to 6
  m.group(i); 

  //and access the 6 tokens:
  //COOP
  //166657
  //NEW IBERIA AIRPORT ACADIANA REGIONAL LA US
  //200001
  //177
  //553
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a performance difference between doing split and searching if the string is two letter and not 'US' , or just doing the regex? Or is there a faster way of going about this?

Comment: the split could be faster, but regexp engine are damn fast too: to tell the difference write a couple of timed tests. Note that you could easily filter your file with a combination of tools like awk and sed from command line.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`".* ([A-Z][A-Z]) US.*"`

if some states aren't abbreviated perhaps try:

`" ([a-z][A-Z])+ US'"`

Answer (score 0):

Pay special attention to the `^` beginning of the line, non greedy group `(.*?)` , end of line `$`, `DOTALL` and `MULTILINE`.

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^(.*?):(.*?),'(.*?)',(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)$", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

---

Regex DEMO:

https://regex101.com/r/bX0rS3/1

---

Live JAVA Example:

http://ideone.com/uAUaJT

---

Regex Explanation:

```
^(.*?):(.*?),'(.*?)',(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)$

Options: Case sensitive; Exact spacing; Dot matches line breaks; ^$ match at line breaks; Default line breaks

Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) (carriage return and line feed, next line, line separator, paragraph separator) «^»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “:” literally «:»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character string “,'” literally «,'»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character string “',” literally «',»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 4 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “,” literally «,»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 5 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “,” literally «,»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 6 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) (carriage return and line feed, next line, line separator, paragraph separator) «$»
```

Answer (score 0):

You can validate that it is a US state abbreviation with:

```
\s(?:(A[KLRZ]|C[AOT]|D[CE]|FL|GA|HI|I[ADLN]|K[SY]|LA|M[ADEINOST]|N[CDEHJMVY]|O[HKR]|P[AR]|RI|S[CD]|T[NX]|UT|V[AIT]|W[AIVY])(?:\sUS'|'))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zW1gF8/2)